# why can't i run my app? why is it showing the message below?

Tags: android, debugging

i am trying to run a app from android on my phone, but everytime i try i receive the following messeng error and i cant run my app. can anyone help me?

- I created a empty activity and i tried to run it, but everytime i try it it shows the messeng below.
- I have tried several solutions on the internet, but none seens to be working.
- I have tried a lot of forum, but none seens to have the exatly problem i have.

[image]

Comment: Have you set Launcher Activity in Manifest file?

Comment: yes, its already set.

Comment: Restart or recreate your emulator

Comment: Please include the results as text, not as a picture, particularly not as picture that is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

There will be multiple solutions to this, possibly one could work:

- Try to Invalidate Cache/Restart Android Studio.
- Check does your phone is in developer mode or not.
- Have you provided permission of USB Debugging to your phone.
- In your manifest file. Add below line to your launcher activity:

  `android:exported="true"`

These could be possible solutions for your problem, as per my knowledge.